# wkhtml2pdf Bold text while conversion

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtml2pdf for converting html file to pdf.
But there is a problem when i add an image to the page all the text in that page appears in distorted bold font.
If i remove the image then the text is fine. 
This problem appears only while viewing in Adobe reader. In foxit it looks fine.
I am using php to generate the html and then convert it into pdf using shell script.
Kindly help if you have any idea about this problem.

Comment: Could we see an example of the HTML? I would be interested in testing this.

Comment: The problem was resolved. This was due to some transparent background in the image.